# GET request htaccess redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect url from

**website.com/search.php?city=india&keyword=laptop**

to
**website.com/search/india/laptop**

How can i do this with htaccess

Present code in my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ search.php?city=$1&keyword=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?city=([^&]+)&keyword=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /search.php?city=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: justdlal.com/search.php?city=india&keyword=laptop still remains same but not redirecting to justdlal.com/search/india/laptop

Comment: One more help... urls are parsing as justdlal.com/search/india/lenovo+laptop+dealers  How to remove those + signs in string so that url is  justdlal.com/search/india/lenovo-laptop-dealers

Comment: That is very different problem from this question. Please create a new question with that and I will try to answer it.